# Get height of listview cells to ease scrolling upwards

Tags: java, android, listview

An activity with a listview has a problem that is, the listview will have different amount of content in each cell. When the user scrolls down, the listview is smooth and things work as expected. **But, when the user scrolls up, the cached data of the listview is reloaded**. This redraw is making the listview scrolling up jumpy. What I figured out is that, if I calculate the height of each cell while scrolling down and save it in an ArrayList and apply the same height when the user scrolls up against the visible listitem then the jumpy scroll can be fixed. I have tested the same by setting a static height for every post, the scrollbar was not jumpy. **But, I have to make it dynamic according to each cell height**. The listview code might look to be a little complex!

The **activity**:

```
public class PostListActivity extends Activity implements OnScrollListener {
    TableLayout html_output_table;
    int id = 0;
    List<String> dataFromParse = new ArrayList<String>();
    LazyObjectDrawingAdapter adapter;
    ListView listView;
    List<RichPost> richPostArrayList = new ArrayList<RichPost>();

    private int currentScrollState;
    private int currentVisibleItemCount;
    private int skipParam = 0;
    private boolean flag_loading = false;

    int mLastFirstVisibleItem = 0;

    HashMap<integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<integer, String>();

    int initialHeight = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> heightList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int position;

    boolean scrolling = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_list_list);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        // Need to create the adapter constructor
        listView.setOnScrollListener(this);
        adapter = new LazyObjectDrawingAdapter(PostListActivity.this, dataFromParse, richPostArrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        setContent();
        // cityListBody("Hello");

    }

    public void setContent(){

        // Pull data from Parse
        HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("userid", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
        params.put("skip", skipParam);

        ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("studentsPosts", params, new FunctionCallback<List<List<ParseObject>>>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<List<ParseObject>> data, com.parse.ParseException arg1){
                if (data == null) {

                } else {
                    Log.e("size ", "RUNNING Size :   " + data.size());

                    if (data.size() > 0) {
                        flag_loading = false;
                        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                            RichPost rc = new RichPost();
                            //if (heightList.size()>i){
                                Log.e("heightList.size()", ""+heightList.size());
                            //}
                            if (data.get(0).get(0).get("htmlContent") != null) {
                                // Switch i to 1 to force just 1 additon.
                                dataFromParse.add(data.get(i).get(0).getString("htmlContent"));
                                rc.setHtmlCode(data.get(i).get(0).getString("htmlContent"));
                                Log.i("Calling notifiyDataSetchanged", "now");
                            }
                            if (data.get(i).get(0).get("photos") != null) {

                                List<ParseFile> pFileList;
                                pFileList = (List<ParseFile>) data.get(i).get(0).get("photos");

                                rc.setPhotosArray(pFileList);

                            }
                            if (data.get(i).get(0).getParseFile("photo") != null) {
                                // Time to retrieve the photo
                                ParseFile getParseFile;
                                getParseFile = (ParseFile) data.get(i).get(0).get("photo");
                                rc.setPhoto(getParseFile);
                            }

                            richPostArrayList.add(rc);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState){
        this.currentScrollState = scrollState;
        this.isScrollCompleted();
    }

    private void isScrollCompleted(){
        if (this.currentVisibleItemCount >= 5 && this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount){
        this.currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;

        if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount != 0) {
            if (flag_loading == false) {
                flag_loading = true;
                Log.d("IN ON SCROLL", "NOW: " + skipParam);
                skipParam = skipParam + 10;
                setContent();
            }

        }


        // to determine scroll up or down
        if (mLastFirstVisibleItem < firstVisibleItem) {
            Log.i("SCROLLING DOWN", "TRUE");
//          View c = listView.getChildAt(0);
//          int scrolly = -c.getTop() + listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() * c.getHeight();
//          Log.e("scrolly", "" + scrolly);
            int scrolly = getItemHeightofListView(listView, firstVisibleItem);
            Log.e("scrolly down", "" + scrolly);
            //setting the cell height from total height - initial height
            heightList.add(scrolly-initialHeight);
            ArrayListGetterSetter test = new ArrayListGetterSetter();
            test.setList(scrolly-initialHeight);
            initialHeight = scrolly;
            //hashMap.put(firstVisibleItem, "" + scrolly);
            //Log.e("Item show",""+heightList.get(firstVisibleItem));
            scrolling = true;
        }
        if (mLastFirstVisibleItem > firstVisibleItem) {
            Log.i("SCROLLING UP", "TRUE");

//          View c = listView.getChildAt(0);
//          int scrolly = -c.getTop() + listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() * c.getHeight();
//          Log.e("scrolly", "" + scrolly);
//          int scrolly = getItemHeightofListView(listView, firstVisibleItem);
//          Log.e("scrolly up", "" + scrolly);
            if (firstVisibleItem <= heightList.size()) {
            //getting the heights from the arraylist while scrolling up 
            //Log.e("Item show",""+heightList.get(firstVisibleItem));

            position = firstVisibleItem;
            }
        }
        mLastFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;

    }

    public static int getItemHeightofListView(ListView listView, int items) {

        ListAdapter mAdapter = listView.getAdapter();

        int listviewElementsheight = 0;
        // for listview total item height
        // items = mAdapter.getCount(); 


        for (int i = 0; i < items; i++) {

            View childView = mAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            childView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            listviewElementsheight+= childView.getMeasuredHeight();
            }


            return listviewElementsheight;

        }


}
```

The **adapter**:

```
public class LazyObjectDrawingAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    PostListActivity postList = new PostListActivity();
    RichPost rc = new RichPost();

    Context mContext;
    List<String> randomItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<RichPost> richPostArrayList = new ArrayList<RichPost>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    ArrayList<Integer> heightList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public LazyObjectDrawingAdapter(Context context, List<String> contentComingIn, List<RichPost> richPostArrayList) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.randomItems = contentComingIn;
        this.richPostArrayList = richPostArrayList;

    }
//  public LazyObjectDrawingAdapter(Context context, List<String> contentComingIn, List<RichPost> richPostArrayList, ArrayList<Integer> heightList) {
//      this.mContext = context;
//      this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
//      this.randomItems = contentComingIn;
//      this.richPostArrayList = richPostArrayList;
//      this.heightList = heightList;
//
//  }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        //return 1;
        //Log.i("GetCount size : ", " " + randomItems.size());
        //return 1;
        return randomItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return randomItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View vi = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lazy_adapter, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            setIds(vi, holder);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }

        ArrayListGetterSetter test = new ArrayListGetterSetter();
        Log.e("test.getSize()", ""+test.getSize());
        //test.getListValues(position);
        tryingNewClass(holder, vi, mContext, (String) randomItems.get(position), richPostArrayList.get(position));

        return vi;
    }

    private void step1(String fromActivity) {
        Log.d("Html output", "" + fromActivity);
    }

    private void step2(String html){
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Element element = doc.body();
        Elements elements = element.select("img");
        Log.w("Size of the elements ", " " + elements.size());
        for(Element e : elements){
            Log.d("step 2: ", "img: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    private void step2PicksUpWorks(String html){
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements imgs = doc.body().select("p");
        for (Element e : imgs){
            if(!e.toString().contentEquals("")){
                Log.i("Img sources ", ": " + e.ownText());
            }
        }
    }

    private void tryingNewClass(ViewHolder holder, View view, Context context, String source, RichPost richPost){
            //setting static height for testing, feel free to remove it anytime 
            int heightValue = 500;
            holder.textToDraw.setMinHeight(heightValue + 200);

        TestDrawableClass tdc = new TestDrawableClass(source, holder.textToDraw, context, holder.imageToDraw, richPost);
    }

    private void URLCombinedTest(int position, ViewHolder holder, View view, Context context, String source){

        ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        URLCombined uip = new URLCombined(position, iv, context, tv);
        Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(source, uip, null);
        tv.setText(spanned);
        //holder.linearLayoutForImages.addView(iv);
        holder.linearLayoutForImages.addView(tv);

    }

    /*
     *  Time to do the on draw 
     */

    private void lineByLine(int position, ViewHolder holder, View view, Context context, String source){
        //Need to get line by line and then run it via the test parsers and add it to the layout dynmically via the ViewGrou parpent
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(source);
        Element element = doc.body();



        Elements ele = element.select("img");
        for (int i = 0; i < ele.size(); i++) {
/*          Log.w("For loop ", " " + i + " "+  ele.get(i).html());
            Log.d("For loop ", " " + i + " "+  ele.get(i).text());
            Log.i("For loop ", " " + i + " "+  ele.get(i));*/
            addURLImageParser(position, holder, view, context, ""+ele.get(i));
        }

        Elements all = doc.select("b");
        for (int i = 0; i < all.size(); i++) {
            Log.i("For loop ", " " + i + " "+  all.get(i));
            addURLTextParser(position, holder, view, context, ""+all.get(i));
        }

        Log.w("About to start a loop to check everything ", "now");
        int imgValue = 0;
        for (Element el:doc.select("body").select("*")) {
            imgValue++;
              // loop over all textnodes of these children
            Log.i("Element siblings ", " " + el.nextElementSibling() + " "  +imgValue);
            Element tempElement = el.nextElementSibling();
            if(el.nextElementSibling() == null){
                Log.w("Element is null", "value is : " + el + " " + imgValue);
            }

            if(el.nextElementSibling() != null){
                //Loop through the siblings.
                if(el.nextElementSibling().hasText()){
                    //Log.d("Can we check any text after the fact ? ", " " + el);
                    //Log.e("Element has text: ", " " + el.nextElementSibling());
                }

                if(el.nextElementSibling().hasText() == false){
                    Elements elements = tempElement.select("img");
                    if(elements.isEmpty() == false){
                        //Log.e("Element text is false ", " " + elements);
                    }
                }
            }

        imgValue = 0;
        }
    }



    private void addURLTextParser(int position, ViewHolder holder, View view, Context context, String source){
        Log.w("in add text url", "now");
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);

        URLTextParser utp = new URLTextParser(tv, context, 0);
        Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(source, utp, null);
        tv.setText(spanned);

        holder.linearLayoutForImages.addView(tv);
        //Now attach it the layout
    }

    private void addURLImageParser(int position, ViewHolder holder, View view, Context context, String source){
        //Log.w("in add image url", "now");
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
        URLImageParser uip = new URLImageParser(position, iv, context);
        Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(source, uip, null);

        holder.linearLayoutForImages.setId(position);
        holder.linearLayoutForImages.addView(iv);

    }

    private void testURLTextParser(int position, ViewHolder holder, View view, Context context, String source){
        //Lets just get text only
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(source);
        Elements img = doc.body().select("p");
        for (int i = 0; i < img.size(); i++) {

            //Log.w("Checking null ", " " + img.get(i).text().contentEquals(""));
            if( img.get(i).text().contentEquals("") == false){
                Log.i("output : ", " " + img.get(i).text());
                Log.d("Output2 ", " " + img.get(i).html());

                URLTextParser utp = new URLTextParser(holder.textToDraw, context, 0);
                Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(img.get(i).html(), utp, null);
                holder.textToDraw.setText(spanned);

            }

        }

    }

    private void testURLImageParser(int position, ViewHolder holder, View view, Context context, String source){
            //Log.d("In step 3 ", " Position :  " + position);



            //Lets do some crazy work right now. So lets start with just images. Make them 3 seperate ImageViews to draw
                //Pos 0 has three images, but lets cycle throgh the mfirst
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(source);
                Elements img = doc.body().select("img");
                //Now we have all possible image 'source links'

                for (int i = 0; i < img.size(); i++) {
                    //Lets loop through them one by one
                    Log.w("checking the output of the img ", "" + img.get(i).toString());
                    ImageView iv = new ImageView(context); //Create a holder for the images
                    URLImageParser uip = new URLImageParser(position, iv, context); 
                    Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(img.get(i).toString(), uip, null);
                    holder.linearLayoutForImages.addView(iv);
            }


    }


    private void setIds(View vi, ViewHolder holder) {
        holder.textToDraw = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textOnly);
        holder.imageToDraw = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageOnly);
        holder.linearLayoutForImages = (LinearLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.linearForImages);
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textToDraw;
        ImageView imageToDraw;
        Object objectCouldBeAnything;
        Canvas toTry;
        LinearLayout linearLayoutForImages;
    }

}
```

Class **ArrayListGetterSetter**:

```
public class ArrayListGetterSetter {

    ArrayList<Integer> heightList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int valueFromList;
    int size;

    public int getListValues(int itemIndex) {

        valueFromList = heightList.get(itemIndex);
        return valueFromList;
    }

    public void setList(int value) {
        heightList.add(value);
    }

    public int getSize(){
        size = heightList.size();
        return size;
    }

}
```

Class **TestDrawableClass**:

[Click to see the code](http://justpaste.it/iw7u)

The

```
 ArrayListGetterSetter test = new ArrayListGetterSetter();
        Log.e("test.getSize()", ""+test.getSize());
```

in the `LazyObjectDrawingAdapter` is always returning 0. Thus querying the elements are causing null pointer exception. **How can I get the height values?**

Answer (score 0):

in getItemId you should have returned position instead of zero.

```
@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
```

it should be :

```
@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

i think this might help.

Comment: Will that help in getting the height of each cells?